# DNN Error - General Exception - AbsoluteURL

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I have an DNN site where i get this error alot (and i mean alot) and i cant find the source to the problem!

Is there anyone who has an idea of where to start looking or how to debug this?

I cant find the fault its impossible.. :(

```
DNN PLATFORM
v. 09.01.01 (129)
4.6 .NET FRAMEWORK

General Exception

Site name
AbsoluteURL /Default.aspx DefaultDataProvider DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider 
AbsoluteURL:/Default.aspx

DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

ExceptionGUID:d1a7b7bf-b7fa-4b86-ab6d-a3efabebf994

AssemblyVersion:

PortalId:-1

UserId:-1

TabId:-1

RawUrl:

Referrer:

UserAgent:

ExceptionHash:jn6m7y6lLHEjghJrIXICAWzADhA=

Message:Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

StackTrace:

at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Pane.IsVesionableModule(ModuleInfo moduleInfo) at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Pane.InjectModule(ModuleInfo module) at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.InjectModule(Pane pane, ModuleInfo module)
InnerMessage:

InnerStackTrace:

Source:mscorlib

FileName:

FileLineNumber:0

FileColumnNumber:0

Method:

Server Name:SERVERNAME
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am getting a similar issue when adding a specific module to a page

Comment: I figured out that my custom module *.dnn file was not correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022655/dnn-error-general-exception-absoluteurl

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue is because "PortalAliasId" column in "TabUrls" table consists of value "1", by default this should be NULL instead.

https://dnnsupport.dnnsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021667014-Accessing-the-page-settings-fails-to-retrieve-content